# Retrieve values from the Map using the index

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I have a map something like this-

`ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>> tableList`

which will have data like this-

Sample Example-

```
{table1={DRIVER=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver, PASSWORD=stage_cs_user, URL=jdbc_url, SUFFIX=xt1, SQL=sql, USER=user}, table2={DRIVER=driver_name, PASSWORD=pass, URL=jdbc_url2, SUFFIX=xt2, SQL=sql2, USER=user}}
```

I am trying to iterate through the above map-

```
class Task implements Runnable {

private Connection[] dbConnection = null;
private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>> tableLists;

public Task(ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>> tableNames) {
    this.tableLists = tableNames;
}

@Override
public void run() {

for (int i = 0; i < tableLists.size(); i++) {

dbConnection[i] = getDBConnection(tableLists.get(i).get("URL"), tableLists.get(i).get("USERNAME"), tableLists.get(i).get("PASSWORD"), tableLists.get(i).get("DRIVER"));
    }
  }
}
```

And it is giving me `Null Pointer Exception` in the `get call`. Is there anything I am missing here? If yes how can I fix it? As I need to assign the `dbConnection` as 0 and 1 depending on the `tableLists` size.

**Updated Code:-**

After making changes like this-

```
private Connection[] dbConnection = null;


        int j=0;
        for (Map<String, String> map : tableLists.values()) {

            dbConnection[j] = getDBConnection(map.get("URL"), map.get("USER"), map.get("PASSWORD"), map.get("DRIVER"));
            callableStatement[j] = dbConnection[j].prepareCall(map.get("SQL"));

            methods[j] = getRequiredMethods(map.get("SUFFIX"));
            j++;
        }

private Connection getDBConnection(String url, String username, String password, String driver) {

    Connection dbConnection = null;

    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    }

    return dbConnection;
}
```

It is again throwing NPE, but this time it is throwing as soon as it makes the connection and return back. What wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Map` interface has a `Key`, not an index.  To get all the entries, try

```
int i=0;
dbConnection = new DbConnection[tableLists.size()];
for (Map<String, String> map : tableLists.values()) {
  dbConnection[i] = getDBConnection(
    map.get("URL"), 
    map.get("USER"), 
    map.get("PASSWORD"), 
    map.get("DRIVER"));
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mel for the suggestion. So I can put all these things inside the `run method` right?

Comment: Updated the question with the problem I am facing now. Again I am getting NPE now. But this time as soon as the connection is made and returns back, it throws NPE

Comment: Please post the new problem as a separate question.  Putting multiple topics in the same entry will make it less useful for those who come afterwards.

Comment: Actually, the problem might be that you stored as "USER" and loaded as "USERNAME" -- should match.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be getting the values like

```
tableLists.get(0);
tableLists.get(1);
```

Since Map is not index based collection, its key based. You should be getting the values like

```
tableLists.get("table1");
tableLists.get("table2");
```

since your keys are "table1" and "table2" and not 0 and 1.

***Edit:***
So you can modify your source as below.

```
int i = 0;
for (String mapkey : tableLists.keySet()) {
    dbConnection[i] = getDBConnection(
            tableLists.get(mapkey).get("URL"), 
            tableLists.get(mapkey).get("USERNAME"),
            tableLists.get(mapkey).get("PASSWORD"),
            tableLists.get(mapkey).get("DRIVER"));
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion then how can I make it to work in that for loop? As I don't want to hardocde tablename in the get method. Is there any way of doing it without hardcoding the tableNames?

Comment: @Nevzz03 Updated the reply. Please check the same.

Comment: Thanks Jayamohan. I have also updated the question after making the changes, I am getting NPE again but this time it is coming after making the connection